# Polymer 2 site cant find resources in Safari

Tags: safari, polymer, polymer-2.x

I built this site http://danielleandsteven.wedding/ and it loads fine in most browsers. In Safari, I get a lot of errors that it cant load resources and the my-app elem is empty.

A quick glance of the list of 404 resources- it looks like some of them are for nonexistent components and others are in /bower_components/ but its looking for them in the base directory.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on Edge 15 and I got
`Object doesn't support property or method 'call'`.

You could add the Babel Polyfills?
https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

it adds some basic function that babel code may depend on - and as you probably served transpiled ES5 code (with babel) to those browsers it might be your problem.